# Threejs UV coordinated texture out of size problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I am creating texture with canvas. I am using UV algorithm and I found at stack overflow. But i think, this uv algorithm creating faces like box geometry and my texture look like this photo. How can i write this text to dragged area ?

[image]

UV code:

```
assignUVs(object) {
      object.geometry.computeBoundingBox();

      const {max, min} = object.geometry.boundingBox;

      const offset = new THREE.Vector2(0 - min.x, 0 - min.y);
      const range = new THREE.Vector2(max.x - min.x, max.y - min.y);

      object.geometry.faceVertexUvs[0] = object.geometry.faces.reduce(
          (acc, val) => {
              const v1 = object.geometry.vertices[val.a];
              const v2 = object.geometry.vertices[val.b];
              const v3 = object.geometry.vertices[val.c];

              acc.push([
                  new THREE.Vector2(
                      (v1.x + offset.x) / range.x,
                      (v1.y + offset.y) / range.y
                  ),
                  new THREE.Vector2(
                      (v2.x + offset.x) / range.x,
                      (v2.y + offset.y) / range.y
                  ),
                  new THREE.Vector2(
                      (v3.x + offset.x) / range.x,
                      (v3.y + offset.y) / range.y
                  )
              ]);

              return acc;
          },
          []
      );

      object.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
  }
```

Comment: Are there any restrictions to use [.offset](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture.offset)?

Comment: nope, i don't know but, when i delete offset textures are not visible